# A site where I can find antonyms of german words?

Tags: meaning

I want a site where I can find opposite of an adjective in German. For example, gross should be klein, hell should be dunkel and so on.

I am, however, unable to find such a site. Can someone advice?

Comment: Good online dictionaries (Wiktionary, for example) tend to list antonyms and synonyms for German words.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that one @tofro

Comment: @tofro: Please do not post answers in the comments. Please write proper answers instead. https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/1487

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Consult a dictionary" is a very obvious answer, but not one that is "worth" an answer. I was about to request a close because of that, but decided to be a bit nicer. Thanks for criticising me of being nice, I appreciate it. If I had wrote an answer providing the link to Wiktionary, I'm sure you'd have criticised me for "providing a link-only answer".

Comment: @tofro: I also was thinking about closing this question for a moment, but I still find it legitimate, because it's about the German language, and "consult a dictionary" is not a good answer to this question, because the OP obviously doesn't know where to find such resources (this is exactly what he asks for). And when someone asks for websites, what else could be the main part of an answer but a list of links?

Comment: Btw: Link-only answers are discouraged only if the content of the linked site easily could written as text here in German.stackexchange. But in this case this would mean do provide every possible antonym of every German word, and this 1. far beyond the scope of German.stackexchange and 2. not what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the website

[was-ist-das-gegenteil-von.de](https://was-ist-das-gegenteil-von.de/)

Comment: While the linked page well adresses the question, answers cotaining a link only are typically not well receiced here, sine the link may stop working.  I suggest to add a bit of explanation giving alternatives as well.

Comment: @guidot I see the point however what other answer is there to a question literally asking for a site?